# Setting up watches in Angular controller vs. more complex template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm looking for the proper place to put some presentation-related logic in Angular. I'm new to Angular, so I'd like some general guidance as to the proper Angular way to approach a problem like this.

I have an object that encapsulates a user's sort choices for a list of data points (called "samples"). Sorts can be ascending or descending and can be based on the sorted object's description or a numeric value from one of two matched collections  (measurements and deficiencies).

Sorting works great, but now I want to put a legend on-screen that shows how the sort is configured. Here's my first stab at a directive:

```
sampleSort.directive('sampleSortLegend', ['SampleSort', function(SampleSort) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var classes = [];
      var name, directions;
      if (SampleSort.isByDescription()) {
        name = 'Sample Description';
        directions = ['A to Z', 'Z to A'];
      } else {
        name = SampleSort.elementName();
        if (SampleSort.isByDeficiency()) {
          clasess.add('deficiency');
        }
        directions = ['lowest to highest', 'highest to lowest'];
      }
      $scope.sortName = name;
      $scope.sortClasses = classes;
      $scope.sortDirection = SampleSort.isAscending() ? directions[0] : directions[1];
    },
    template: 'Sorted by: <strong ng-class="sortClasses">{{sortName}}</strong> ({{sortDirection}})',
  }
}]);
```

This gives me the result I want, except that it's totally non-interactive because those three scope properties never change. To fix this, would it be better to:

1. Set up a **$watch in the controller** to update the scope when the critical responses of my SampleSort changes;
2. Assign the SampleSort model to the scope and **move the display logic into the template**; or
3. Something else?

I think I am drawn towards #1 because I find code easier to read than these templates. With logic moved into the template, the code might look something like this (which doesn't work quite right but will serve the purpose for this question):

```
sampleSort.directive('sampleSortLegend', ['SampleSort', function(SampleSort) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.SampleSort = SampleSort;
    },
    template:
      'Sorted by: ' +
      '<strong ngIf="SampleSort.isByDescription()">Sample Description</strong>' + 
      '<strong ngIf="SampleSort.isByMeasurement()">{{SampleSort.elementName()}}</strong>' + 
      '<strong ngIf="SampleSort.isByDeficiency()" class="deficiency">{{SampleSort.elementName()}}</strong>' +
      ' (' +
        '<span ngIf="SampleSort.isByDescription()">{{SampleSort.isAscending() ? "A-Z" : "Z-A"}}</span>' +
        '<span ngIf="!SampleSort.isByDescription()">{{SampleSort.isAscending() ? "lowest to highest" : "highest to lowest"}}</span>' +
      ')',
  }
}]);
```

Again, I don't necessarily need help with these particular chunks of code, just something like "#1 is more in line with Angular orthodoxy, but you should also..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ideal answer. With your soluton #2 (you say go drawn towards #1 but actually implemented #2), your directive becomes dependant on the `SampleSort` service, which is fine if you don't intent to reuse it in different contexts (such as bind it to a differet SampleSort, or some inherited data).

Assigning SampleSort to the scope is fine but all these `SampleSort.isByMeasurement` methods will be called on each digest cycle (which happen pretty often in Angular world), so make sure they are trivial and fast-processing functions.

If the methods are heavier (or could become eventually), you should rather go for solution #1 where you control what you watch and when you refresh the view. Should you re-execute all methods on each digest, or should you rather watch a specific indicator (like some `SampleSort.lastUpdated` property).

Alternatively, you can also rely on events: when your SampleSort gets changed, it would fire a global event (`$boradcast`) that your directive would catch and update accordingly.

Basically, go for what seems to you simpler and easily maintenable, and keep in mind the performance cost of each solution.

Comment: Thanks. My point in implementing #2 was to show how the template gets kind of ugly (IMO). I guess I should implement #1 to see how much uglier it gets.

Comment: Implemented #1, I like the efficiency of one watch point and the code seems cleaner to me. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: Glad you could sort it out. Note that your example with #2 maybe was not working because you were using `ngIf=...` instead of `ng-if=...` in your HTML.